# Modifying data using awk

Tags: bash

In a long file i'm searching for something like this:
`c 0.5p_f`
`10 px 2`

I need to modify a 3rd column of a line after 'c 0.5p_f' marker.

It's part of a bash script that would do this and i would like to avoid using, like, awk scripts, only bash commands.

Comment: So why no AWK? Does that mean no `sed` or `grep`, too?

Comment: OK, the question is "modifying data using awk" but you don't want to use awk?

Comment: please avoid tagging your question with the things you actually explicitly not want. (I've removed the awk tag.)

Comment: So i see, a little misunderstanding here. I don't want to use external awk script file becouse i only want to use my bash script in which one of the step will use awk. I'm not good at this so sorry for bad explanation. I want only one file, script.sh which will do some stuff, one of them is modifying lines like in question above, but everything must be within one file - script.sh . I hope that explains something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use `awk`?  It's perfect.

```
do_modify{$3="modify";do_modify=0}/c 0\.5p_f/{do_modify=1}1
```

If you can use `sed` scripts,

```
/c 0\.5p_f/{n;s/\([^[:space:]]*[[:space:]]\+[^[:space:]]*[[:space:]]\+\)\S*/\1modify/}
```

would do.  Not that pure Bash is hard either, though.

```
do_modify=
while read -r line; do
    if [[ -n ${do_modify} ]]; then
        columns=(${line})
        columns[2]=modified
        line=${columns[*]}
        do_modify=
    fi
    printf '%s\n' "${line}"
    if [[ ${line} = *'c 0.5p_f'* ]]; then
        do_modify=1
    fi
done
```

Comment: +1, but you could use an `N;P;D` style instead of `x;g;p;d;g` style.

Comment: @Dennis: Thanks; I revisited it and I think just `n` is sufficient.